# compare checksum of files between two remote servers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, checksum

On my local box `"machineA"`, I have two folders `"/primary"` and `"/secondary"`. These two folders have some files in it. Now on the remote server `"machineB"` I have one folder `"/bat/snap/"` which contains lots of file.

All the files in `"/primary"` and `"/secondary"` folders in `"machineA"` should be there in `"machineB"` remote server in this directory `"/bat/snap/"`. Now I need to compare checksum of all files in `"/primary"` and `"/secondary"` folder on local box `"machineA"` with remote server in this directory `"/bat/snap/"`. If there is any mismatch in checksum then I want to report all those files that have issues in `"machineA"`.

I wrote one command that I am running on `machineA` but it gives me an error:

```
find /primary/ /secondary/ -type f | xargs md5sum | ssh machineB '(cd /bat/snap/ && md5sum -c)' | egrep -v 'OK$'
```

Below is the error I am getting and after that I stopped my above command. I checked both the servers and I can see this file is present so what's wrong then?

```
md5sum: /primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data: No such file or directory
/primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data: FAILED open or read
```

Comment: maybe permission? try to run as root

Comment: why? both have access to same user and its all passwordless setup.

Comment: someone don't have access to file, you check the same command on machine A and it's works, so machine B cannot access or because the path is not correct, permission, different version of MD5SUM... what else can it be?

Comment: I already tried btw and still same issue.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just sync files with `rsync`?

Comment: @l0b0 I dont want to copy files just compare the checksum but if there is any other better way, I am up for it? Basically I want to put this command in a shell script and fail the script if I can find any files whose checksum doesn't matches.

Comment: Is that file a symlink to a non-existent file?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick There is no symlink at all here. Just files are copied here.

Comment: The other possibility is that there is no file `/primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data` on machineB. Maybe the file is `/bat/snap/primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data`.

Comment: I have checked all the files are there in both the machines.

Comment: Does `a=/primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data; md5sum $a; ssh machineB  md5sum $a` produce any errors?

Comment: This is the output I got `7b72823de9r9db1f10b70d6c2c8140b0  /primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data
md5sum: /primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data: No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169519/discussion-between-user5447339-and-mark-plotnick).

Comment: What is the output of `a=/primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data; ssh machineB ls -l $a`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick on machineB, path is different for that file it doesnt start with `/primary/` but instead it starts with `/bat/snap/`. Full file path on machineB: `/bat/snap/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data`

Comment: md5sum just uses whatever pathnames you give it. Use relative pathnames. `(cd /primary && find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +; cd /secondary && find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +) | ssh machineB '(cd /bat/snap/ && md5sum -c)'`

Comment: Yeah looks like it is working this time and it is printing out stuff like this `./abc_monthly_197_proc_7.data: OK
./abc_monthly_1678_proc_7.data: OK
./abc_monthly_1555_proc_7.data: OK
./abc_monthly_1512_proc_7.data: OK
./abc_monthly_1536_proc_7.data: OK`. Is there a possibility to get full path name instead? Also it is very slow, not sure why? Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick you still around?

Comment: How to speed it up would be a good question to ask over on https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with multiple path from machineA included in the filename processed over in machineB... the following command isn't pretty but worked for me, hope it helps.

```
find /primary/ /secondary/ -type f | xargs md5sum | awk -F'/' '{print "echo "$1 $NF " | ssh user@machineB \"(cd /bat/snap/  && md5sum -c)\""}' | bash
```

Comment: yeah looks like it works but its kinda very slow. is there any way to make it fast or do in parallel?

Comment: ssh to remote host for every file definitely isn't very efficient.  parallel could speed it up by doing it concurrently for more files, but the more efficient way is likely to tweak the command a bit so it ssh to machineB and get all the md5sum in one shot.